# Anylogic select agents after Pickup

Tags: java, anylogic

After agent A picked up agents [a, b, c, ...],
how can I select the picked up agent, for example, c, without using Dropoff?

I'm new to Anylogic, so pardon me if the question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Within the pickup object itself, you can use `container.contents()` to get a list of the agents picked up already. `container` refers to the agent picking up.

Afterwards, the agent that picked up agents can access them using `.contents()`.

Some examples are in the [help](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/pickup.html#pickup):
[image]

Comment: Thank you Benjamin,
The problem I'm see here is that, for example, the agent being picked up has one property called qty. And at the next block I tried `traceln(agent.contents.get(0).qty)`, I then through me `qty cannot be resolved` error. I printed the typle of `agent.contents.get(0)`, it gives me `combined.A` (assuming the picked up agent type is A)

Comment: Please always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum. Also, upvote answers when they actually solve the original question. Happy to help with this new issue, just create a new post. Why? See https://benjamin-schumann.squarespace.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I was also in that situation and doing this worked: `((Order) container.contents().get(0)).pathNodes`. Putting the agent type in parantheses.